# Can a static electric field with a curl generate a changing magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, vector-fields

Maxwells equations state that $$\nabla \times E = -\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}$$.

The classic example is that a changing magnetic field will produce a curl in the E field and so a current, but is the reverse true too for a case with $\frac{dE}{dt}=0$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed. Like a changing magnetic field can create an electric field, similarly a changing electric field can create a magnetic field. This is stated by one of the Maxwell's equations:

$$\nabla \times \mathbf B =\mu_0 \mathrm {\mathbf j} + \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \mathbf E}{\partial t} $$

Thus, there are two main sources of magnetic fields, either a current or a changing electric field.

Comment: My question wasn’t this but whether a STATIC electric field with a curl could induce a changing magnetic field using the above formula?

Comment: @AlexGower The curl of an electrostatic field is zero. The field only has curl if the field is an induced electric field. So if you are talking about electrostatic fields, then the question doesn't make sense as these field are irrotational.